# How is "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page? " generated in browsers?

Tags: browser, refresh, modal-dialog

I have a page where I open a "modal window". It is really just a DIV, with an IFRAME inside, where I load another page. When I want to refresh the page, the browser pops up a window saying "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page? Reloading this page will cause the modal window to disappear. Press OK to continue, or Cancel to stay on the current page."

How does this message get generated? How does the browser figure out that I have a modal window there, because I don't use any window.open() call from JavaScript? Is there any way to disable this behavior of the browser.

Comment: Let me know what site you are working on so I can avoid it.

Comment: erm, stackoverflow does this! and, what's more, it's a good thing for avoiding losing changes you've written on a page.

Comment: Disable JavaScript in your browser settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be `body.onunload` in the source of the page loaded in the IFRAME.

As the modal window is essentially an IFRAME, then when you close (or refresh) the main window, the browser knows it is killing that IFRAME, hence any `body.onunload` in that IFRAME fires.

Comment: You're right. Actually I am working with the Wicket framework and I searched in their source code, and look what I found:

window.onbeforeunload = function() {   
  return "Reloading this page will cause the modal window to disappear.";
}    

Fortunately this can be disabled easily. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function that handel onbeforeunload, automaticaly the Firefox message is generated.

you can disable it by returning null at the and of your handler.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by some script modifying all off-site links to display this modal window, and then *return true*, or *return false* based upon your interaction with the modal window.

If you want to strip that behavior, you could remove all click events for external links.